# How to use dynamic scoping with devise and omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, routes, omniauth

I am upgrading an old app from rails 3.0 to rails 4.1 and having trouble setting up the routes for devise and omniauth.  Currently the routes look like this:

```
scope "(:locale)", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do
      devise_for :users, controllers: {
            omniauth_callbacks: "users/omniauth_callbacks"
      }
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
 Devise does not support scoping omniauth callbacks under a dynamic segment (RuntimeError)
 and you have set "/(:locale)/users". You can work around by passing
 `skip: :omniauth_callbacks` and manually defining the routes. Here is an example:

match "/users/auth/:provider",
  constraints: { provider: /google|facebook/ },
  to: "devise/omniauth_callbacks#passthru",
  as: :omniauth_authorize,
  via: [:get, :post]

match "/users/auth/:action/callback",
  constraints: { action: /google|facebook/ },
  to: "devise/omniauth_callbacks",
  as: :omniauth_callback,
  via: [:get, :post]
```

I've tried to manually define routes a number of ways but when I run my tests none of my routes work.  Does any one know the correct way to handle these dynamic segments with devise_for?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I added devise_for 2 times in *routes.rb*

```
devise_for :users, skip: [:session, :password, :registration], controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: "users/omniauth_callbacks" }

scope ":locale", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do
   devise_for :users, skip: [:omniauth_callbacks]
```

Found the answer [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2813)

In addition, you need a custom failure block for omniauth to handle errors during login (E.g. user cancels):

```
# In config/initializers/omniauth.rb
require 'devise/omniauth'
# Work around for bug when scoping paths
# See: https://github.com/spree/spree_social/issues/130
OmniAuth.config.on_failure = Proc.new do |env|
  env['devise.mapping'] = Devise.mappings[:user]
  controller_name  = ActiveSupport::Inflector.camelize(env['devise.mapping'].controllers[:omniauth_callbacks])
  controller_klass = ActiveSupport::Inflector.constantize("#{controller_name}Controller")
  controller_klass.action(:failure).call(env)
end
```

Comment: Looks like a good answer, I'll have to test it later though. This has given me hope!

Comment: The solution on Devise wiki works very well: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-OmniAuth-inside-localized-scope

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add to the solution provided on devise's wiki: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-OmniAuth-inside-localized-scope

If you're already using a setup phase (`setup: true` in devise.rb), you can skip creating a new controller (`omniauth_controller.rb` in their example) and simply add `session[:omniauth_login_locale] = I18n.locale` to the `setup` action. Eventually my `routes.rb` looks like this:

```
  devise_for :users, skip: [:session, :password, :registration, :confirmation], controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: 'omniauth_callbacks' }

  scope '(:locale)', locale: /en|zh/ do
    devise_for :users, skip: :omniauth_callbacks

    devise_scope :user do
      get 'auth/:provider/setup' => 'omniauth_callbacks#setup'
    end
  end
```